# Declaring class methods in Zope interfaces

Tags: python, interface, zope

Consider a class like the following:

```
from zope.interface import implementer

@implementer(IMessage)
class Foo:

  @classmethod
  def parse(Klass, msg):
  """
  Parses `msg` into an instance of :class:`Foo`.

  :returns obj -- An instance of :class:`Foo`.
  """
```

How would I specify the class method in the Zope interface `IMessage`?

Using the `@classmethod` decorator in Zope interfaces results in

```
zope.interface.exceptions.InvalidInterface: Concrete attribute, parse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zope interfaces don't care about class methods; they only specify what API a specific interface must implement. Note that you specify methods *without* the `self` parameter, for example. This way, you can implement an interface any way you like, including using regular functions in a module!

If the implementation chooses to make that callable a `classmethod` is entirely outside of the scope of interfaces. Interfaces only care about what API you'd use when you access interface providers; if an instance has a callable then the end-user shouldn't need to care if that is a class method.

If the class method should be available on the class directly, then that's the interface the *class* must provide; lets call it the factory interface here:

```
class IMessageFactory(Interface):
     def __call__():
         """Produce an IMessage provider"""

     def parse(msg):
         """Parses `msg` into a IMessage provider"""


class IMessage(Interface):
     """A message interface"""

     # Optional, show the class method here too
     def parse(msg):
         """Parses `msg` into a IFoo provider"""
```

Your `Foo` class directly provides `IMessageFactory`, and implements the `IMessage` interface (so that it's instances provide it).

Comment: Thanks! The differentiation in factory and instance interfaces makes sense and exposes intentions quite clear.